# Using a cgo shared library in a Go program

Tags: c, go, cgo

Trying to test `cgo`, so I wrote the below:

```golang
//go:build lib
// +build lib

package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world")
}

func main() {}

// go build -tags lib -buildmode=c-shared -o golib.a lib.go
```

And compiled it as:

```sh
$ go build -tags lib -buildmode=c-shared -o golib.a lib.go
```

Trying to use the generated shared lib in another code as:

```golang
//go:build app
// +build app

package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "golib.h"
import "C"

func main() {
    C.HelloWorld()
}

// go run main.go
```

But I'm getting the below error:

```sh
# command-line-arguments
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_HelloWorld", referenced from:
      __cgo_a844f0d618a1_Cfunc_HelloWorld in _x002.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_a844f0d618a1_Cfunc_HelloWorld)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
# command-line-arguments
cgo-gcc-prolog:47:33: warning: unused variable '_cgo_a' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Moreover, I'm getting the below error with VS code at mac:

```sh
go list failed to return CompiledGoFiles. This may indicate failure to perform cgo processing; try building at the command line. See https://golang.org/issue/38990
```

[image]

Comment: Regardless of the build errors, you cannot use a cgo shared library in a Go program, because you cannot have multiple Go runtimes in the same process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a cgo shared library in a Go program, because you cannot have multiple Go runtimes in the same process.

Trying to do so will give the error:

```
# command-line-arguments
cgo-gcc-prolog:67:33: warning: unused variable '_cgo_a' [-Wunused-variable]
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x43fd5e2]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw({0x40a875b?, 0x1c00011b800?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:992 +0x71 fp=0x1c00004a960 sp=0x1c00004a930 pc=0x402f6d1
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.sigpanic called from 0x43fd5e2
stack: frame={sp:0x1c00004a960, fp:0x1c00004a9b0} stack=[0x1c00004a000,0x1c00004b000)
....
0x000001c00004aaa0:  0x0000000000000000  0x0000000000000000 
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:781 +0x3a9 fp=0x1c00004a9b0 sp=0x1c00004a960 pc=0x4043449
exit status 2
```

To call c code from go, there are 3 potential approaches:

1. Inline coding, as:

```golang
package main

//#include  <stdio.h>
//int Add(int a, int b){
//    printf("Welcome from external C function\n");
//    return a + b;
//}
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(C.Add(5, 2))
}
```

2. Static linking, where you have both `.c` and `.h` files, as:

```c
// lib.c
#include  <stdio.h>
int Add(int a, int b){
    printf("Welcome from external C function\n");
    return a + b;
}
```

And

```
// libadd.h
int Add(int, int);
```

And the go file be:

```golang
// main.go
package main

// #include "libadd.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := C.Add(1, 2)
    fmt.Println(x)

}
```

We have to run the file as `go run .` or `go run github.io/xxx`
// go run main.go will not work as it will consider main.go only, and not consider the C file

3. Dynamic linking, where you compile the above `c` file as `clang -shared -fpic -Wall -g lib.c -o libadd.so` and have the go file as:

```golang
// main.go
package main

//#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
//#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -ladd
//#include "libadd.h"
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := C.Add(1, 2)
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Here you can use `go run main.go` as the library is connected through the hard code, to distribute the binary, the shared library `loadadd.so` is required to be distributed with the same binary file and existing in the same folder.

I uploaded separate folders for each case [here](https://github.com/hajsf/tutorial/tree/master/ffi).

**BONUS**
To call the generated share library in go using a c program, we can use the below:

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libadd.h" // calling C file
#include "libgo.h" // calling shared library generated by GO

int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
    int x = Add(1, 2);
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the file as:

```bash
clang -o main -L. -ladd -lgo main.c   // -ladd => -l (library) is libadd
```